# TypeError: must be str, not float

Tags: python, string

this is 1/8 of my script:

```
print('Your skill:', int(charskill))
with open('C:\Documents and Settings\Welcome\My Documents\python\Task 2\lol.txt', 'w') as myFile:
    myFile.write(charskill)
```

Once I execute on python, it gives me an error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Welcome\My Documents\python\Task 2\Dice generator v2.py", line 39, in <module>
    myFile.write(charskill)
TypeError: must be str, not float
```

How do I fix this problem? I want the file to run on notepad ;/ because it is my homework at school.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.x (it's possible you might be given your `print`), then instead of using `.write` or string formatting, an alternative is to use:

```
print('Your Skill:', charskill, file=myFile)
```

This has the advantage of putting a space in there, and a newline character for you and not requiring any explicit conversions.

Answer (score 8):

You should pass `str` object to [`file.write`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#file.write). But it seems like `charskill` is `float` object.

Replace following line:

```
myFile.write(charskill)
```

with:

```
myFile.write(str(charskill)) # OR   myFile.write(str(charskill) + '\n')
```

or

```
myFile.write('{}'.format(charskill)) # OR  myFile.write('{}\n'.format(charskill))
```

to convert `float` to `str`.

Answer (score 1):

Try casting your float to a string before writing it:

```
myFile.write(str(charskill))
```